# Can't access Google Cloud Compute engine external IP to access flask app

Tags: python, flask

i've build a simple flask app on my google cloud GCE instance, but i can't access it from another computer, here's the simple flask app that i've build :

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, json, abort
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def heartbeat():
  return 'hello'
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
```

and when i run the app

[image: and when i run the app]

and access the external IP of my machine it only said this site can't be reached   [image: it only said this site can't be reached]
 i have set up a new firewall rule [image: set up a new firewall rule]
 but it still not working.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? if so, how?

Comment: nope, still error, have to postpone this project right now untill i find the solution

Comment: I found the problem. It's because you need to change the port from a 5000 to a webserver port

Answer (score 0):

It's because you've to change the port to 80 instead of 5000

Comment: do i need to change the port to 80 on both the firewall rule and the flask app? cause i get an error when i change the port to 80 on the flask app and run it, thanks for the answer by the way :D !

Comment: @AlwiMuhammad, how is the error? Is it when you try to enter your website? If so maybe try to add *http://* before your ip-address. However maybe try to change your firewall to ```default-allow-http```, that is the firewall I'm using

Answer (score 0):

with me it was the silly problem that when you click on the link to the external IP on the GCP console you get send to https://34.##.#.## and that doesn't work but if you go to 34.##.#.##:5000 it did work for me. Also doing a "curl 34.##.#.##:5000" on linux also works for me

Answer (score 0):

When I did this my problem was I didnt configure the windows firewall correctly at first.
Make sure to allow inbound rules like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can try:

- Change the URL from Https to Http
- Use port 80 first, and add :80 after the URL